# Taking Screen Shot while the device is connecting with MAC

Tags: ios, iphone, macos

I have device.I connected with the MAC.I press the two buttons that are Home and Sleep/Wake.After that screen shot  is added to the Camera Roll in the Photos app.And i tried to copy that i could not do that.Please anyone help me to do this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply you can do this, if you do the following steps

1.Click the photo that you want to copy and paste.

2.Click Import Photo.That is above on the photos.

3.Now you can see that photo.

4.Right Click that photo or directly drag it from the photos to your required image folder.

5.You can see the options of photo if you right click that.

6.Then just copy that.

7.Paste in your required image folder.

Comment: Once you do that.Let me know whether my description is correct or wrong.